# Post xml data from body of Postman

Tags: xml, postman

I am working with Rest API of GEOSERVER with NODE JS and I want to post a XML formatted style via Postman

I have done it with JSON and it worked but how it is possible with XML.

My style is :

const style =

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld 
    StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
     <Name>defaultxx_line</Name>
     <UserStyle>
       <Title>Defaultxx Line</Title>
       <Abstract>A samplexx style that draws a line</Abstract>
       <FeatureTypeStyle>
         <Rule>
           <Name>rule1</Name>
           <Title>Blue Line</Title>
           <Abstract>A solid blue line with a 1 pixel width</Abstract>
           <LineSymbolizer>
             <Stroke>
               <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
             </Stroke>
           </LineSymbolizer>
         </Rule>
       </FeatureTypeStyle>
     </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>`
```

I have added this to body of Postman and and selected 'XML(application/xml)'.

In my code I wrote `const style = req.body.style` like I did with JOSN format but not working.

Comment: What do you mean by `style`? Are you talking about just posting a request with a xml body via Postman? What are you receiving on your app?

Comment: style is xml formated body containing a layer's style in Geoserver.